# How to interpret the US law for Emergency Use Authorization

Tags: united-states, fda

Does the list of requirements in this law below mean that the Secretary must follow all requirements to satisfy the EUA or it's up to the secretary which ones are required?

https://uscode.house.gov/view.xhtml?req=granuleid:USC-prelim-title21-section360bbb-3&num=0&edition=prelim

> (c) Criteria for issuance of authorization
>
> The Secretary may issue an authorization under this section with respect to the emergency use of a product only if, after consultation with the Assistant Secretary for Preparedness and Response, the Director of the National Institutes of Health, and the Director of the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (to the extent feasible and appropriate given the applicable circumstances described in subsection (b)(1)), the Secretary concludes-
>
> (1) that an agent referred to in a declaration under subsection (b) can cause a serious or life-threatening disease or condition;
>
> (2) that, based on the totality of scientific evidence available to the Secretary, including data from adequate and well-controlled clinical trials, if available, it is reasonable to believe that-
>
> (A) the product may be effective in diagnosing, treating, or preventing- (i) such disease or condition; or (ii) a serious or life-threatening disease or condition caused by a product authorized under this section, approved or cleared under this chapter, or licensed under section 351 of the Public Health Service Act [42 U.S.C. 262], for diagnosing, treating, or preventing such a disease or condition caused by such an agent; and
>
> (B) the known and potential benefits of the product, when used to diagnose, prevent, or treat such disease or condition, outweigh the known and potential risks of the product, taking into consideration the material threat posed by the agent or agents identified in a declaration under subsection (b)(1)(D), if applicable;
>
> (3) that there is no adequate, approved, and available alternative to the product for diagnosing, preventing, or treating such disease or condition;
>
> (4) in the case of a determination described in subsection (b)(1)(B)(ii), that the request for emergency use is made by the Secretary of Defense; and
>
> (5) that such other criteria as the Secretary may by regulation prescribe are satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

There is an "and" at the end of (4), so the Secretary must conclude that all of (1)-(5) hold in order to issue an authorization.    Similarly, to satisfy (2), it must be reasonable to believe both of (2)(A) and (2)(B).  However, in (2)(A), the product may be effective in diagnosing, treating or preventing either (i) or (ii).